# Calling a function pointed to by void(*vptr)() from an instance of that class

Tags: c++, callback, void-pointers

This is a public member in `CSpellData.h`:

```
void (CSpellData::* _vptr)();
```

It gets assigned a callback in the constructor, like this:

```
_vptr = GetCallbackFromID(spell_id);
```

where:

```
void (CSpellData::* CSpellData::GetCallbackFromID(ESpellID spell_id))() {
    switch (spell_id) {
    case ESpellID::FIREBALL:
        return &CSpellData::FireballCallback;
    case ESpellID::STONESKIN:
        return &CSpellData::StoneskinCallback;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, in my `Spell.h`, I have a pointer to `CSpellData`, like this:

```
const CSpellData* _c_spell_data;
```

How can I now call the function pointed to by `_vptr` using the `_c_spell_data` pointer?

ChatGPT couldn't help me for over an hour, it kept giving me responses like this:

```
//(c_spell_data.*c_spell_data._vptr)();
//(c_spell_data->*_vptr)();

//_c_spell_data->_vptr();
```

which all give errors about functions with 0 arguments, and so on. The only way it compiles is like this:

```
_c_spell_data->vptr;
```

but then the callback doesn't actually trigger.

Please help me!

I tried everything, from taking references to pointers, to const casting, to asking chatGPT.

Comment: `(_c_spell_data->*_vptr)();` is a valid syntax of those three, but the answer: You cannot call it, because `_vptr` is not a pointer to a **const** member function.

Comment: [OT]: `auto CSpellData::GetCallbackFromID(ESpellID spell_id) -> void (CSpellData::*) ()` would probably be more readable.